# How to ignore columns in my google sheet script

Tags: google-sheets

This is part of my script that tells the data from my entry form where to go. I need it to not look at columns G-I when it looks for the next empty row. How do I do that?

```
enter code here   if(validateEntry()==true){



  var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; //identify the next blank row

  //code to update the data in the database sheet

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B4").getValue()); //Issue Date

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B6").getValue()); //Requested By

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B8").getValue()); //Market

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B10").getValue()); //Job Name

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B12").getValue()); //Type

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B14").getValue()); //Subcontractor

  shUserForm.getRange("B6").clearContent();
  shUserForm.getRange("B8").clearContent();
  shUserForm.getRange("B10").clearContent();
  shUserForm.getRange("B12").clearContent();
  shUserForm.getRange("B14").clearContent();

  }

}
```

Comment: what is in G:I?  chances are it'd be better practice to keep those columns empty UNTIL there's data in A:F.

Comment: As part of our sheet, it's a checkbox and some area for comments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the checkboxes from the unused rows.  then add a simple line of code that will ADD checkboxes whenever a new entry comes in.

That way .getLastRow() will work fine and the sheet will look cleaner.